# Saving image tags to a pivot table in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Pardon my newb question, this question is mostly due to my stubborn lack of understanding of many to many relationships in Laravel.

On my site, users can upload images

```
$images = new Images;
...
$images->save();
```

accompanied by tags that the users create themselves. These tags are stored as an array, validated, then checked if the tag exists. If the tag exists, I want an entry on 'tagmap' that relates the new image to that tag. If it doesn't exist, I want the same thing to happen but also have a new tag be created.

I have 3 tables, an image table, a tags table, and a pivot table called 'tagmap' which only has the columns 'image_id' and 'tag_id'.

So after the image is saved :

```
$tags = new Tag;        
foreach ($request->tags as $tags ) {
    if(preg_match('/^[a-zA-Z]+[a-zA-Z0-9._]+$/', $tags)) {
        if (strlen($tags) < 21) {
            if (Tag::where('tagname', $tags)->count() > 0) {
                //store tag_id and image_id association on 'tagmap' table, no need to create new tag because tag exists
            } else {
                //create new tag on the 'tags' table
                //store tag_id and image_id association on 'tagmap' table
            }   
        } else {
            return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Tags may only contain 20 characters.');    
        }   
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()->with('info', 'Tags may only contain letters and numbers, and must start with letters.'); 
    }
}       
$tags->save();
```

The commented out sections is where I'm having trouble.

Here is my Tag model :

```
class Tag extends Model {
  protected $table = 'tags';

  protected $fillable = [
      'tagname',
  ];

  public function Images() {
      return $this->belongsToMany('CommendMe\Models\Images');
  } 
}
```

and in my Images model I have:

```
class Images extends Model {

  protected $table = 'images';

  public function tags() {
       return $this->belongsToMany('CommendMe\Models\Tag');
  } 

}
```

any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel automates the pivot table process if you have proper naming conventions.

In this case, you have `images` and `tags`, therefore your intermediary table should be named `image_tag`.

Then if you want to associate the tags with the image, you can utilize the `sync()` method. If you have tags previously associated, you can use `syncWithoutDetaching()`.

```
$image->tags()->sync(['array', 'of', 'tag', 'ids']);
```

Alternatively, you can use the `syncWithoutDetaching()` method if you don't want to destroy existing relationships:

```
$image->tags()->syncWithoutDetaching(['array', 'of', 'tag', 'ids']);
```

Comment: Odd. Why image_tag instead of images_tags ? Also, why $image->tags() instead of $images->tags() ? I already did $images = new Images; so why does it become $image . The syntax going on here is very confusing.

Comment: @FelixMaxime Laravel automates the table name relationship process. It looks for the singular name between the model. So in this case images as a singular is image and tags as a singular is tag. It's also always alphabetical. So `image_tag` is necessary in this case.